# Python - Unicode & Character Encodings in Python

Tags: python, replace, utf-8, decode, encode

I encounter a lot of encoding and decoding problems so I read a lot about it but I just can't get a grip on it. The logic just confuses me and escapes me so I'm kind of lost.
To extend my knowledge and read through:
https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/#enter-unicode

There is this example which I executed but I get another result as on the website:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("résumé".encode("utf-8"))
# b'r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9'
print("El Niño".encode("utf-8"))
# b'El Ni\xc3\xb1o'

print(b"r\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9".decode("utf-8"))
# 'r�sum�'
print(b"El Ni\xc3\xb1o".decode("utf-8"))
# 'El Ni�o'
```

As you can see, the decoding gives me the diamond shape characters with a question mark. The correct result should be:
'résumé'
'El Niño'
What is happening here? What mistakes do I make?

I use Visual Studio Code. Python version 3.12.2. Beautifulsoup version 4.12.3. I'm on Windows 11. Files encoding is set to:
[image: Files encoding setting]

Comment: From what you've shown here, your code and your editor are fine. Your *terminal*, though, would appear to be using a font that does't have a `é` or `ñ` character to display.

Comment: (If it were an encoding issue in your terminal, each of the non-ASCII characters would be displayed as *two* question-mark glyphs, one for each byte in the UTF-8 encoding of the single Unicode character.)

Comment: This seems to work for me as expected `print("résumé".encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: Note that the default is `"utf-8"` so you can also just do: `print("résumé".encode().decode())`

Comment: Thanks for replying. That said, the suggestions given by JonSG seems to work for him but not for me. When I execute both lines of code  they give me these results: r�sum�
r�sum�. Perhaps a terminal issue on my side a chepner pointed out.

Comment: Not a font problem, since you are seeing the glyph for the replacement character rather than the .notdef glyph .i.e. `é` is being converted to `\uFFFD`. If you type the command `chcp` in the vscode terminal, what output do you get?

Comment: If I type the command  `chcp` the result is `Active code page: 850`. [MyOutput](https://imgur.com/a/4rEvMXp) But I've made a mistake running the code presented by JonSG. I did run it while in output window which gave me this result: `r�sum� r�sum�` . But when I run it in the terminal I get the correct result: `résumé résumé`   [MyOutput](https://imgur.com/a/xHVDCJc)   Still, I don't understand that the result is different in terminal vs output window.

Comment: It's a *PowerShell* terminal so I'd expect a discrepancy in/between `$OutputEncoding` vs. `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding`; switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).